# Chrome 67 broke my WebComponent 

Tags: google-chrome, web-component

For some strange reason, the update from Chrome 66 to Chrome 67 broke my web application's WebComponents.

The map at the top is defined via a WebComponent custom element. It should be noted that it isn't rendered through a shadow DOM. It is rendered directly by appending a child `<img>` to my map component.

[image: Chrome 66 vs 67]

Chrome 66's DOM:

```
<bj-map ...>
  <img src="...">
</bj-map>
```

Chrome 67's DOM:

```
<bj-map ...></bj-map>
```

The component's class is `Map`, extending from `HTMLElement`. Non-relevant methods have been removed.

```
class Map extends HTMLElement {

  connectedCallback () {
    this.render()
  }

  render () {
    const src = this.getMapSource()

    this.innerHTML = `
      <img src="${src}"></img>
    `
  }
}

customElements.define('bj-map', Map, { extends: 'div' })

export default Map
```

Are there any ways that I can try to debug this magical issue?

Comment: Are there any errors in Chrome DevTools? Try removing `{ extends: 'div' }`, Map is extending `HTMLElement` not `HTMLDivElement`.

Comment: @abraham That was it! (If you write that as an answer, I can accept it as correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `{ extends: 'div' }` from `customElements.define('bj-map', Map, { extends: 'div' })`.

`class Map extends HTMLElement` is not extending `HTMLDivElement` so you don't need to specify an extend in `define`.

[Extending native HTML elements](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements#extendhtml) has additional details.